# Slice a list within a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to slice a list in python so that I get two separate lists: one with the keys, and one with the values. My list looks like this:

```
[(b'a', 2), (b'surprise,', 1), (b'but', 1), (b'welcome', 1), (b'one', 1), (b'for', 1), (b'sure.', 1)]
```

I am relatively new at coding and so I am just wondering how I would be able to do something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netwave has a very correct answer, but here is a straightforward way to do it:

Given that:

```
data = [(b'a', 2), (b'surprise,', 1), (b'but', 1), (b'welcome', 1), (b'one', 1), (b'for', 1), (b'sure.', 1)]
```

You can use a loop to unpack it:

```
keylist = []
vallist = []

for item in data:
  keylist.append(item[0])
  vallist.append(item[1])

# You end up with keys in keylist and values in vallist
```

You can also use "tuple unpacking" to put each tuple into two vars:

```
keylist = []
vallist = []

for k,v in data:
  keylist.append(k)
  vallist.append(v)

# You end up with keys in keylist and values in vallist
```

You can streamline with list comprehensions:

```
keylist = [item[0] for item in data]
vallist = [item[1] for item in data]
```

Just to be obnoxious, you can use tuple unpacking as well:

```
kl,vl = [item[0] for item in data], [item[1] for item in data]
```

Comment: Despite looking less spiffy than `zip(*whatever)`, this has the major advantage of actually working properly on empty input.

Comment: I wrote it so a new python user could see a simple way to do it.  Many ways to do the same.

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip` unpacking the data:

```
>>> l = [(b'a', 2), (b'surprise,', 1), (b'but', 1), (b'welcome', 1), (b'one', 1), (b'for', 1), (b'sure.', 1)]
>>> [*zip(*l)] # similar to list(zip(*l))
[(b'a', b'surprise,', b'but', b'welcome', b'one', b'for', b'sure.'), (2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

If you want lists instead of tuples, use a comprehension:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*l)]
[[b'a', b'surprise,', b'but', b'welcome', b'one', b'for', b'sure.'], [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

For fixing if `l` is an empty list you can use combiantion with an `or` expresion:

```
>>> keys, values = [*zip(*[])] or ([], [])
>>> keys
[]
>>> values
[]
```

Comment: Be aware that this does the wrong thing if `l` happens to be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Since you specifically use the terms "keys" and "values", you can do it via a dictionary:

```
my_dict = dict(my_list)
my_keys = list(my_dict.keys())
my_values = list(my_dict.values())
```

If all you care about is some kind of (read only) iterable, don't bother wrapping in `list`.

Comment: This loses input order before Python 3.6, and relies on there being no duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`:

```
l = [(b'a', 2), (b'surprise,', 1), (b'but', 1), (b'welcome', 1), (b'one', 1), (b'for', 1), (b'sure.', 1)]
l1, l2 = map(lambda x: x[0], l), map(lambda x: x[1], l)
print('l1 is: {}\nl2 is: {}'.format(list(l1), list(l2)))
```